# Monthly effective interest rate to 6-month effective interest rate

Tags: finance

I am given that the monthly effective interest rate is $1\%$ and I would like to find the 6 month effective interest rate for a problem.

I used the formula $r_e=(1+r)^\frac{m}{n}-1=(1+.01)^\frac{12}{2}-1=.0615=6.15\%$

Since I am going from effective to effective interest, I am unsure if I should still use the effective interest formula. Or if this form of the formula is correct. Do I just multiply $1\%$ by $6$?

Any help is appreciated, I am having a hard time figuring out all the subtleties with interest rate.

Comment: Your calculation is correct.

Comment: Please don't post your questions on multiple SE sites: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37952/conversion-of-1-month-effective-interest-rate-to-6-month-effective-interest-rat